# How do I create more verbose result messaging for a Jmeter Junit Sampler

Tags: java, logging, junit, jmeter

I've noticed that when I run a  Junit sampler with Jmeter, the messaging is pretty bare. If an exception occurs, Jmeter will report it, but everything else that happens in my tests has to get outputted using Log4J or another logging tool. Is there a way just to log result back to Jmeter? Do they have an API for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked into the simple data writer as an option?

You could also do a BeanShell script to parse and write results to a file.

Answer (score 1):

You can append the assertion results to a log file.

1. Check on "Append assertion errors" and "Append runtime exceptions"
2. Add listener "View Results in Table"
3. Specifya file name and check on "Errors" in "Write results to file/ Read from file" section. YOu could also click "Configure" button to add more information to the output file.